# Where is the validation hidden?

Tags: validation-list-items

I have a list that includes some sort of validation. It's not the simple validation formula in the list settings, but obviously embedded somewhere else in the system... and I'm wondering where?

Date field #1 is not allowed to be after date of date field #2.

I am a user with some elevated permissions, but I don't access to everything. Where can I look?

Answer (score 0):

It could be jquery or server side validation.

To check if the validation is done using client side javascript or jquery, just hit `F12` of your browser, open the `sources` tab and see if there is any custom js files loaded. You can then find the code within js if its there!

If not, then it may have done using server side coding